# how to verify pdflatex installed and available in PATH

Tags: latex

I have Ubuntu 20 with Grafana and following the github link for the setup of pdf.
https://github.com/IzakMarais/reporter/blob/master/readme.md

I have installed pdflatex with below commands.

```
# apt-get install texlive-latex-base texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-extra texlive-latex-extra
# apt-get install texlive-full
```

after this how i can set and verify environmental veriable.

Kindly help on this to accomplish.

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  as in Ubuntu Core 20?  Ubuntu uses the *year* format for releases that are *snap* only, where `apt` and `apt-get` will only give errors.  Ubuntu Core 20 relies on `snap install`

Comment: Dear i am not facing any issue related with installation as i already installed successfully. my question is how i can verify and set environment variable for pdflatex

Comment: Why do you believe you need to set an environment variable? the `pdflatex` command should be installed to a location that is on the default Ubuntu PATH. You can verify with `pdflatex -version` or `pdflatex -help` for example.

Comment: What is the output of `which pdflatex` ? Does it differ from `/usr/bin/pdflatex`?

Comment: root@localhost:~# which pdflatex
/usr/bin/pdflatex
root@localhost:~#

Comment: this is same /usr/bin/pdflatex